# How to handle 404 error on server in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-status-code-404

I have use below code:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPage/Default.aspx">
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/ErrorPage/Default.aspx"/>
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ErrorPage/Default.aspx"/>
      <error statusCode="400" redirect="~/ErrorPage/Default.aspx"/>
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/ErrorPage/Default.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

The above code is working fine in localserver but when uploading on the server then 404 exceptions is not redirected to the error page.

I get below Error in server:
[image]

Comment: Do you have any transformation on you web.config file?

Answer (score 0):

create this methode in global.asax

```
    public void Application_Error()
    {
    var routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values.Add("controller", "yourControllerNameForError");
        routeData.Values.Add("action", "YourActionMethodeForError");

        if (exception is HttpException httpException)
        {              
            switch (httpException.GetHttpCode())
            {
                case 404:            
                    routeData.Values["action"] =  "Your404MethodeError";
                    break;                 
            }
        }

        Server.ClearError();
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        IController errorController = new ErrorController();
        errorController.Execute(new System.Web.Routing.RequestContext (
             new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
}
```

Comment: I have tried this one also:
  
    void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        var serverError = Server.GetLastError() as HttpException;
        if (serverError != null)
        {
            if (serverError.GetHttpCode() == 404)
            {
                Server.ClearError();
                Server.Transfer("~/ErrorPage/Default.aspx");
            }
            if (serverError.GetHttpCode() == 500)
            {
                Server.ClearError();
                Server.Transfer("~/ErrorPage/Default.aspx");
            }
        }
    }

Comment: But still 404 error was not redirect to error page.